# Why my thread is keep running?

Tags: java, multithreading

im trying to implement a thread tutorial and this is the class where i  have extended thread class .

```
package training;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Threadtutorial  extends Thread{
    Date now;
    Locale place;
    //int i;

    public void run(){
        int i=0;
        while(i<1){
        now = new Date();
        place = new Locale("en");
        //timeFormatter t = new timeFormatter();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        DateFormat d  ;
        DateFormat d2;
        d=DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, place);
        d2=DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, place);
        //String d2=d.format(now);
        String ass=sdf.format(now);
        String bas=d.format(now);
        String css=d2.format(now);

        //String bss=sdf.format(ass);
        System.out.println("start");
        //System.out.println(ass);
        System.out.println(bas);
        System.out.println(css);
        i--;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }}

}
```

and below is my class which executes the thread.

```
package training;

public class Threadexecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Threadtutorial t= new Threadtutorial();
        //for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        t.start();
        Threadtutorial t2= new Threadtutorial();
        t2.start();


    //}

    }
}
```

Now why my thread is keep running?why i cant use stop method?

Comment: You have `while(i<1)` and `i--`. So if `i` starts at 0 subtracting one from it each iteration will continue until it underflows.

Comment: So, it is an infinite while loop. Have you tried calling interrupt() from another thread? That will ïnterrupt" it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it infinite. Once `i` is decremented past -2^31 it should underflow to (2^31)-1. This would be greater than `1` and terminate the loop. You just need to wait for over 2 billion iterations of that loop

Comment: To address the second part of your question, [Thread.stop() is severely broken](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--) and no one should use it, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(i<1)
```

you are decrementing `i` so `while` is infinite

```
i--;
```

Comment: oh god, im sure this must be the stupidest question in the history of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only decrementing the variable i. It is always less than 1. This way you have an infinite loop.